# Python handle different .bash variable versions

Tags: python, bash, maven

I'm writing a Python script to update maven passwords. To find the path to `mvn` and the `file-path` I use `M2_HOME` and `M2_REPOS` like this

```
mvn = os.environ['M2_HOME'] + "/bin/mvn %s %s"
real_files_path = os.environ['M2_REPOS']
```

The problem is that some of my coworkers have `M3_HOME` or `M3_REPOS` set in their .bash files. So I need a more generic solution to get `mvn` the `file-path`.

Comment: Do not use M2_HOME anymore only set the PATH to the binary which is `bin/mvn` ....What is M2_REPOS?

Comment: I need M2_HOME because some might not have installed mvn to the default folder. M2_REPOS is our working directory for maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the only problem you face is different environment variable names, you could use (and chain) the [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method like this :

```
mvn = os.environ.get("M2_HOME", os.environ.get("M3_HOME"))
real_files_path = os.environ.get('M2_REPOS', os.environ.get("M3_REPOS"))
```

This way, python will first try to find the `M2...`variables first, and if not defined will fall back on the `M3...` one.